# Magento Product View Show from my new extention

Tags: magento

I want show on my product view page from my default theme. Now it is comes from my custum theme. Cani call my product view page to another theme.If yes then please let me know procedure of that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to render product view page from your custom theme, just rename the product view file i.e **view.phtml** in your custom theme. With this way, Magento see the requested file from catalog.xml unavailable in your theme then it will consider the default theme's **view.phtml** file.